# Check if file exists in a folder

Tags: java

I have `String s = "three_v1_FVID121007.jpg".`

How can I check if this file exists in the `C:\` directory or subdirectories?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you want to check if the file "C:\three_v1_FVID121007.jpg" exists on disk?

Comment: Tunaki, its not quite a duplicate because this one is looking for a search, whereas the other one's input is a path. But its the same concept and can probably be used to answer this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  File file = new File("three_v1_FVID121007.jpg");
  if(file.exists()){
      System.out.println("file is already there");
  }else{
       System.out.println("Not find file ");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With apache [commons-io `FileUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html):

```
FileUtils.listFiles(
    new File("C:\\"), // base dir
    new NameFileFilter("three_v1_FVID121007.jpg"), // file filter
    TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE // directory filter
).size() == 1;
```

*(not tested)*